# How align horizontal items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align these elements in mobile view

[image: Desktop View]

I want that on mobile devices the images are on top of the text and not on the side.

[image: Mobile View]

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row vcenter">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
            <h3>Why Us?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-10 items_why">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="/assets/img/icons/destination_expert.png"> 
                <span>Destination Expert</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="/assets/img/icons/faster.png">
                <span>Faster</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="/assets/img/icons/transparent.png"> 
                <span>Transparent</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="/assets/img/icons/cheaper.png"> 
                <span>Cheaper</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is quite common, excited developers working on projects they enjoy just want to see the end result because they are so close. However, in order for us to best help you, please revise your question in a way that is beneficial to potential people who want to find a solution, and others like you who want to find an answer. Please update your question to be more specific about what's not working and include things that you have tried  and show us what you've tried so we have a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>`s containing `<span>`s should be contained in another row so they can be part of another grid within the grid.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row vcenter">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <h3>Why Us?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
          <img src="/assets/img/icons/destination_expert.png">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"> 
          <span>Destination Expert</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
          <img src="/assets/img/icons/faster.png">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <span>Faster</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
          <img src="/assets/img/icons/transparent.png">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <span>Transparent</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
          <img src="/assets/img/icons/cheaper.png"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <span>Cheaper</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try it here: https://www.bootply.com/new